# filtering multiple table mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have several different tables in a schema called err_*. These tables contain different numbers of columns. One has 10 columns and the other has 60 columns etc. In each table, each column is named X1 A1..A2..A3..An etc.

I want to filter all tables so that only records that have an A1..A2..A3..An field with a value other than 'OK' are left in it. How could I do this under mssql

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense. Sample data, expected results, *and **your*** attempts will help us help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just select all columns from the tables and filter the tables by the String you want excluded:

```
SELECT ERR_1.A1, ERR_1.A2, <columns in ERR_1>, ERR_1.AN, ERR_2.A1, <other columns>
FROM ERR_1, ERR_2, <table names>
WHERE
    NOT ERR_1.A1 = 'OK' AND
    NOT ERR_1.A2 = 'OK' AND
    <and so on>
```

There's probably a more elegant way to do this in TRANSACT-SQL, but this is the simplest solution

EDIT: I think I misunderstood the question

Comment: Yes you misunderstood. There are many tables called err_ *. We do not know how many of these tables we have, we only know that each structure looks like the first column X and the others A1..A2..A3..An. We do not know how many An fields there are in the table. Just say that at least one. Where one of these An fields contains anything other than 'OK' then they must be retained.